# Error al desplegar app flask en heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

tengo un problema al desplegar mi app en heroku, en realidad si logro desplegarla pero no funciona, al hacer heroku logs en la consola me encontre con el error

```
 at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=petitnotes.herokuapp.com request_id=97994c95-5264-48b4-9b65-667425c20de1 fwd="186.82.84.231" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

intentete arreglarlo con la documentacion que provee heroku `heroku ps:scale web=1`, pero me sale otro error `Couldn't find that process type (web).` he intentado quita y agregando los buildpack, pero aun no sirve

Mi Procfile contiene esto:

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```